# Why isn't my output voltage fully amplified?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, inverting-amplifier

I'm trying to design a circuit with A_v = -20, a swing of +/-2 V, an input resistance of 5 kΩ, and a corner frequency of 3 dB at 100 Hz.

I did the following calculations to get R_E1, R_E2, R1, and R2. I also calculated values for C_I, C_O, and C_E.

I suspect that the issue is with how I calculated R_1 and R_2, but I just can't figure out what I'm missing.

The following are given values: R_C = 3.9 kΩ, R_L = 10 kΩ, and V_2 = 10 V.

[image: Calculations1]
[image: Calculations2]
[image: Circuit]
[image: Analysis]

Comment: What makes you think that your output voltage is *not* inverted?

Comment: "A_v = -20" is inverted too, isn't it? It behaves as expected...

Comment: The DC operating points put the transistor in to a non-linear operating point (saturation).

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of R1 and R2 are trying to place the base at about +4V, which would put the emitter at 3.3V. With 3.3V across about 1K of emitter resistance, you are expecting 3.3mA emitter current, and about the same collector current.

However, look at what that 3.3mA would drop across Rc: \$V_{RC} = 3.3mA \times 3.9k\Omega = 12.9V\$, which is of course impossibly high.

**This transistor is saturated**.

You should aim for about 6 volts at the collector, which is 4V across Rc, for a collector current of:

$$ I_C = \frac{V_{RC}}{R_C} = \frac{4}{3900} = 1mA $$

For 1mA emitter current, you require an emitter potential of:

$$ V_E = I_C \times (R_{E1} + R_{E2}) = 1mA * 960\Omega = 0.96V $$

That would require a base potential of:

$$ V_B = V_E + 0.7 = 1.7V $$

You need to adjust R1 and R2 to obtain this. I suggest you first try R1 = 50kΩ, and see how this yields a better frequency respsonse (gain above unity).

This sets the base potential to:

$$ V_B \approx V_2 \times \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} = 10 \times \frac{10k}{10k + 50k} = 1.7V $$

Of course, you'll need to adjust both R1 and R2 to obtain your desired input impedance, but I'll leave that algebra to you.